# Cargar Tiempo De Temporizador En Java Netbeans

Tags: java

Estoy Creando Un Programa En Java Netbeans En El Que Se Utiliza Un Temporizador, y Lo Que Hace Es Que Cuando El Tiempo Se Acaba Aparace Un JOptionPane Con La Siguiente Leyenda "El Programa Expiro, Contacta Al Administrador Para Activarlo De Nuevo". Ya Esta Echo Pero Mi Problemas Es Que Cuando Cierras El Programa El Tiempo Se Guarda Automaticamente En Un Txt, Pero Al Momento De Llamarlo Carga El Tiempo En Un Label Pero No Inicializa El Temporizador.

Entonces Mi Duda Es Que Al Momento De Llamar Los Datos Guardados En El Txt, Como Puedo Volver a Iniciar El Temporizador? Espero Sus Respuestas Gracias.

Codigo :

```
int x,y;
private Timer t;
private int M = 0, S = 10;

File Guardar = new File("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Downloads\\Cronometro.txt");

private ActionListener acciones = new ActionListener(){

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {   

        S--;
        if( S == -1){
            M = M - 1;
            S = 10;
        }if( M == -1){
            M = 0;
            S = S - 0;
        }if( M == 1 && S == 1){
            Lbl_Aviso.setText("Tu Licencia Esta Por Expirar");
        }if( M == 0 && S == 1){
            Lbl_Aviso.setText("Tu Licencia Expiro");
            M = 0; S = 0;
            t.stop();
            Pasar();
        }
        Cargar();
    }
};

public Crono() {
    initComponents();
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    t = new Timer(1000, acciones);
    t.start();
}

public void Guardar(){
    try{
        if(!Guardar.exists()){
                Guardar.createNewFile();
        }{
        BufferedWriter BW = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(Guardar.getAbsolutePath()));
        BW.write(Lbl_Cronometro.getText());
        BW.close();
        }

    } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.getMessage();
    }
}

public void Cargar(){
    try {
        if (Guardar.exists()){

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(Guardar);

        Lbl_Cronometro.setText(sc.nextLine());
        sc.close();
        }
     } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.getMessage();
    }
}

private void Actualizar() {
    String tiempo = (M+" : "+S);
    Lbl_Cronometro.setText(tiempo);
    Cargar();
}

void Pasar(){
    Activar Pasar = new Activar();
    Pasar.setVisible(true);
    this.dispose();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"La Licencia Expiro, Para Activarlo De Nuevo Contacta Al Administrador");
}

private void Lbl_SalirMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                       
    if(t.isRunning()) 
    {
        t.stop();
        Guardar();
        System.exit(0);
    }
    Actualizar();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En vez de reiniciarlo en **Cargar()**, decide cómo iniciarlo en **Crono()**. Si es la primera vez que ejecuta la aplicación, inicias el temporizador a 1000. Si había información en **Guardar** entonces con la información del fichero.

```
public Crono() {
    initComponents();
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(Guardar);
    String tiempo = sc.nextLine();
    if(tiempo.equals("")) {
         t = new Timer(1000, acciones);
         t.start();
    }
    else {
         t = new Timer(Integer.valueOf(tiempo), acciones);
         t.start();
         Cargar();
    }
}
```

Espero que te sirva. Un saludo

Comment: Hola Gracias Por Responder Pero Sigue Igual, Ya Hice Varios Intentos y Nada.